# Errors while installing dlib library via pip

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, face-detection, dlib

I have no idea what is going wrong with this. I followed a tutorial to install Dlib.

Here is the both way and errors I got. I already installed other known dependencies like cmake, gcc, openCV. downloaded dlib 19.6 from dlib's official website. Python version is 2.7. OS: Windows 10.

Here is the error log from cmd prompt for both way installation.

```
C:\dlib-19.6\dlib-19.6>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running build
Detected Python architecture: 32bit
Detected platform: win32
Removing build directory C:\dlib-19.6\dlib-19.6\./tools/python/build
Configuring cmake ...
-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Failed to run MSBuild command:
    C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:
    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
    Build started 10-Sep-17 7:18:01 PM.
    Project "C:\dlib-19.6\dlib-19.6\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(34,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\dlib-19.6\dlib-19.6\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
    Done Building Project "C:\dlib-19.6\dlib-19.6\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
    Build FAILED.
    "C:\dlib-19.6\dlib-19.6\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
    (Desktop_PlatformPrepareForBuild target) ->
      C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(34,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\dlib-19.6\dlib-19.6\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
error: cmake configuration failed!

C:\dlib-19.6\dlib-19.6>
```

via Python package installer

```
C:\Users\Hp>pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.6.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dlib ... error
  Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\hp\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-vwayhd\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\hp\appdata\local\temp\tmp7vtii4pip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  Detected Python architecture: 32bit
  Detected platform: win32
  Configuring cmake ...
  -- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
  CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
    Failed to run MSBuild command:
      C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
    to get the value of VCTargetsPath:
      Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
      Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
      Build started 10-Sep-17 7:28:49 PM.
      Project "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vwayhd\dlib\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
      C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(34,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vwayhd\dlib\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
      Done Building Project "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vwayhd\dlib\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
      Build FAILED.
      "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vwayhd\dlib\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
      (Desktop_PlatformPrepareForBuild target) ->
        C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(34,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vwayhd\dlib\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
          0 Warning(s)
          1 Error(s)
      Time Elapsed 00:00:00.71
    Exit code: 1
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/Hp/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-vwayhd/dlib/tools/python/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  error: cmake configuration failed!

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\hp\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-vwayhd\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\hp\appdata\local\temp\pip-7vl1fy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    Detected Python architecture: 32bit
    Detected platform: win32
    Removing build directory c:\users\hp\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-vwayhd\dlib\./tools/python/build
    Configuring cmake ...
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
    CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
      Failed to run MSBuild command:
        C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
      to get the value of VCTargetsPath:
        Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
        Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
        Build started 10-Sep-17 7:28:52 PM.
        Project "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vwayhd\dlib\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
        C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(34,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vwayhd\dlib\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
        Done Building Project "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vwayhd\dlib\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
        Build FAILED.
        "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vwayhd\dlib\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
        (Desktop_PlatformPrepareForBuild target) ->
          C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(34,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vwayhd\dlib\tools\python\build\CMakeFiles\3.9.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
            0 Warning(s)
            1 Error(s)
        Time Elapsed 00:00:00.73
      Exit code: 1
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/Hp/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-vwayhd/dlib/tools/python/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    error: cmake configuration failed!

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\hp\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-vwayhd\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\hp\appdata\local\temp\pip-7vl1fy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-vwayhd\dlib\
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your MS Compiler setup but how should we know what exactly is broken. You did not show what you did or which tutorial you used. Being lazy: try anaconda's python dist and use [this](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/dlib) (except you got a good reason against it). Also preparing gcc when trying to install with MS is useless. That's an either this or this decision (and your install tries to use the MS way).

Comment: Thank you @sascha . what would you suggest me...should i go for anaconda or any othe tutorial for installing dlib.?

Comment: anaconda (at least being on win without much experience setting up build-tools). It's also providing [opencv](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv) and all those other difficult to install tools if you can live with the defaults chosen for the binaries (e.g. opencv without ffmpeg i think).

Comment: great!..thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 1):

Windows SDK is not installed on your PC. Download Visual studio installer and install SDK.
[image]